# Memcached Service Crashed Every Morning

Tags: centos, memcached, server-crashes

I have Memcached 1.4.17 Install on CentOS server to serve a PHP website. The problem is every morning the Memcached Service will be crashed. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Any cron tasks at this time? Logs? OOM killer?

Comment: I just checked the server, there is no cron job running at that time period. Could you tell me where to check the Memcached log? How to find the OOM killer?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the logrotate configs? There might be a restart operation, a `kill -USR1`, etc. that might fail to restart the service after shutting it down.